# React when Browser Text Input Changed through Mouse Action

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a text input field and a checkbox.  The checkbox must be disabled if and only if there is input in the text field.  I have a solution that works great for most scenarios:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="search" />
<input type="checkbox" id="cb" />
<label for="cb">Enabled only if no search term</label>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#search').keyup(function (e) {
    var enable = $(this).val() == 0;
    if (enable) {
        $('#cb').removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
        $('#cb').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
});
```

See it [live on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ericjohannsen/WDMCX/).

This works when text is typed or removed using the keyboard, and when text is pasted using the keyboard.

It fails if the user pastes text using the right-click context menu, or if the user presses the little "X" that IE adds to the input field to allow the input field to be cleared.

**Question**

How can I improve the code so that it also works in those scenarios?  Waiting for the textbox to lose focus would provide an inferior user experience.

Comment: You could use the Jquery Realtime validation plugin from [here](http://www.zurb.com/playground/jquery-text-change-custom-event)

Comment: @Cthulhu: That looks awfully cool.  Going to try it out.

Comment: @Cthulhu: Works like a charm!  If you want to turn your comment into an answer (that is more than *just* a link) I'll be glad to accept it.

Comment: It had some issues with IE9 in the past. You might want to check that. It would be a link-only answer, so I think I'll let it live on as a comment :)

Comment: @Cthulhu: I can confirm the issue with IE9, but it's working in IE10.  Any idea what about IE9 might be causing the issue?

Comment: The github page mentions it as a known issue. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg592978%28v=vs.85%29.aspx. I think you might have to work around that in a different way, but I'm not sure how, except for using a `setInterval`, which would be bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Real Time Validation](http://www.zurb.com/playground/jquery-text-change-custom-event) jQuery Plugin solves this issue.  However, it does [not seem to work currently](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15348467/141172) with delegated events.

> Implementing this requires binding events to the keyup event, and a couple other events if you want to detect text changes on cut and paste. Even if you're a JavaScript god it's tedious to keeping writing this logic over and over again. Be smart and use the ZURB text change event plugin instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jquery change method:

http://jsfiddle.net/WDMCX/1/

```
$('#search').change(function() {

    if( $(this).val() === '' ){
        $('#cb').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
        $('#cb').removeAttr('disabled');
    }

});
```

Comment: Please explain the downvotes.  If I am in the wrong I would like to know the correct approach, just like the OP.

Comment: I did not downvote, but *change* will not fire until the text input field loses focus.  Less-than-ideal solution since the focus loss could be to a checkbox that is supposed to be disabled.  Still, might be the only solution.