# Custom Events with bind() vs on()

Tags: jquery

I came across code that adds custom events to detect input text changes originating from either a keyboard or mouse event:

http://www.zurb.com/playground/jquery-text-change-custom-event

The code is a bit older, and the documentation says to use `bind()` to attach the custom events, e.g.:

```
$('#exhibita').bind('hastext', function () {
  $('#exhibitaButton').removeClass('disabled').attr('disabled', false);
});
```

The [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) state

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document. For earlier versions, the .bind() method is used for attaching an event handler directly to elements.

I thought I could just rewrite the code as:

```
$(document).on('hastext', '#exhibita', function () {
  $('#exhibitaButton').removeClass('disabled').attr('disabled', false);
});
```

but the event handler is never triggered.

**Questions**

- Did I make a mistake in my use of `on()`?
- Must the code providing the custom events be rewritten to support `on()`?  If so, what must change?
- Is `bind()` documented to be a candidate for removal in a future version of jQuery?  I did not see a depreciation warning in the docs, but I know `live()` and `die()` were removed from 1.9...
- Is there a future-proof way to use these custom events without rewriting the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are using `on` here is creating even delegation.  This is basically equivalent to the old jquery `live`.

It is possible that this custom event doesn't bubble properly.  Try this instead:

```
$('#exhibita').on('hastext', function () {
```

If bind works, this will work.

Comment: The non-delegated version is working.  Any thoughts on why the custom event might not bubble correctly, or how to fix that?

Comment: I think its more similar to the old .delegate, but I could be wrong. Is that really how .live used to work?

Comment: @Fresheyeball since `document` is used as the first selector, it is the same as `live`.  IF any other selector were used in place of `document` then it would be the same as `delegate`.  `delegate` could also be called with `document` though, in which case it was equivalent to `live` as well.

Comment: @EricJ. Not really sure.  It may have something to do with the internals of the plugin or could even be something in your own code.  Ensure you don't have a handler somewhere in the hierarchy that retuns false or calls `event.stopPropagation`.  You could test this on a page with nothing but `#exhibita` to see if it is your code or the plugin causing the issue.

Comment: @JamesMontagne exactly what I was thinking.

Comment: From the plugin author: `Right, it only works with regular event binding. It does not work with .live(), .on(), or .delegate().` https://gist.github.com/mkelly12/424774.  Any thoughts why that would be?